# Testing that an async method throws an error with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, html2canvas

I have a class with an async method that produces a DOM snapshot using html2canvas. I would like to add a test that will check it handles errors properly. My class looks like this:

```js
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
export class Renderer {
  private readonly window: Window;

  constructor() {
    this.window = window;
  }

  async takeDOMshot() {
    try {
      const newCanvas = await html2canvas(document.body, {
        x: this.window.scrollX,
        y: this.window.scrollY,
        width: this.window.innerWidth,
        height: this.window.innerHeight,
        scale: 1,
        removeContainer: true,
      });

      return newCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

And my test looks something like this:

```js
const renderer = new Renderer();
const html2canvas = jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation(
          (
            body: HTMLBodyElement,
            data: object
          ): Promise<PromiseRejectedResult> => {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("some error"));
          }
        );
      
      expect(async () => {
        await controller.renderer.takeDOMshot();
      }).toThrowError();
    });
```

Notice that I am mocking html2canvas, because it uses the web canvas API, and I do not need to strictly use the API itself for this particular test.

This code does generate an error, but two things seem to be out of place:

1. The error code is `typeError: (0 , html2canvas_1.default) is not a function`, which is not the error I was expecting. I'm assuming that html2canvas is not being mocked properly.
2. The error is not caught by Jest and the expect clause fails with a `Received function did not throw` error.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: 1. You're not mocking the imported module. 2. The method will never throw because you're catching the error